# docker egress filtering / firewall

Tags: docker, dns, docker-swarm, docker-network

Right now I have multiple `docker` instances with `internal` flagged networks. But now I have the need to allow dynamically access to certain egress endpoints (**DNS** and **IP** based).

Is there a way to accomplish this egress filtering within `docker` (?), if not are there any solutions other then create and clean up iptable rules by myself?

> Another solution would be to create a proxy container channeling all traffic and doing the filtering, but I rather would like not to do this.

Comment: I stumbled upon [Træfik](https://traefik.io/) that should allow you to do this, but I'm figuring out how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a suitable Docker networking plugin like Calico, Contiv that supports policy based container networking. For calico policy support, you can refer here(http://docs.projectcalico.org/v1.5/getting-started/docker/tutorials/advanced-policy)